# Excel equation with array constant

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

I want to do `SUMPRODUCT` keeping the first array constant in MS Excel. So when I autofill the cells I want something like  `=SUMPRODUCT(array1,array2)` , `=SUMPRODUCT(array1,array3)`, `=SUMPRODUCT(array1,array4)` and so on.. How can I do this?

Comment: Do you mean you need [absolute reference](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/switch-between-relative-absolute-and-mixed-references-dfec08cd-ae65-4f56-839e-5f0d8d0baca9)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let say array1 is A1:A8, array2 is B1:B8, array3 is C1:C8 .

put `=SUMPRODUCT($A1:$A8,B1:B8)` in A10, then just drag it to C10. USe the '$' sign to 'lock' the reference range/cell.

Hope that solves...  ( :